# Is there a difference in performance between set/save when saving columns to tables?

Tags: kdb

I have a small utility that checks for new columns for an intraday hdb and adds new columns.
At the moment I am using :

```
.[set;(pth;?[data;();();cls]);{[p;e] .log.error[.z.h;"Failed to save to path [",string[p],"] with error :",e]}[pth;]]
```

where path is :

```
`:path_to_hdb/2022.03.31/table01/newDummyThree
```

and

```
?[data;();();cls] // just an exec statement
```

Would it make any difference to use `save` instead:

```
.[save;(pth;?[data;();();cls]);{[p;e] .log.error[.z.h;"Failed to save to path [",string[p],"] with error :",e]}[pth;]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are adding entire columns to a table then you might want to store it splayed, i.e. as a directory of column files rather than as a single table file. This means using `set` rather than `save`.

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/

But test actual example updates.

Comment: It's not what I asked. 
The table is partitioned by date and I need to add columns to it. 
I am not asking whether it is better to have a splayed or date paritioned table, but only if in the situation above save is better then set or viceversa. Basically what's best for saving binaries?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation for [save](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/save/):

Use set instead to save

- a variable to a file of a different name
- local data

So `set` has the advantage of not requiring a global and you can name the file a different name to the name of your in-memory global variable.

There is no difference in how they serialise/write the data. In fact, `save` uses `set` under the covers anyway:

```
q)save
k){$[1=#p:`\:*|`\:x:-1!x;set[x;. *p];   x 0:.h.tx[p 1]@.*p]}'
```

By the way - you can't use `save` in the way that you've suggested in your post. `save` takes a symbol as input and this symbol is the symbol name of your global variable containing the data you want to write.